# PHP prepared statement to query(GET) data from SQL database and post on web page in a while loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql, get, prepared-statement

I want to pull all data rows in my database that have a status=o using a prepared statement. I then want to put that data in my website continuously until it runs out of data in the database. to make it simple, i just want to display the title. I know I need a while loop somewhere (my best guess lol), but im not sure how to do it, or how to structure it. Ive only been learning PHP for a day so I dont know how to code a whole lot. Thanks though.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,title FROM tasks WHERE status=o () VALUES ?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $_GET['id'],$_GET['title']);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = .....(.....): ?>
    <span class="task-listing" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?">
      <span/><?php echo $row['title]?></span>
    </span>
 endwhile;
```

Am I close? Or am I a moron?

Comment: Is this pseudo code or real code? `SELECT id,title FROM tasks WHERE status=o () VALUES ?,?)` is far off and unclear of intentions, should throw an error though. `<span/>` is self closing, is that intentional? `insert into... select` might be what you are after

Comment: this is the best attempt i could give. I have lets say "listings" with titles, and i want them to be displayed on my website. I want the list length = to rows in my database so long as the status column value = "o"

Comment: How do `title` and `id` in the `GET` relate to `listings`? If `o` is a string it should be `status = 'o'`